# A one liner to get the accurate string representation of a multidimensional array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Observe:

```
> var x=[[1,2],[3,4]]
> x
[ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ] ]
> x + ""
1,2,3,4
> x.toString()
1,2,3,4
>
```

I am looking for a one liner to get something like `"[[1,2],[3,4]]"`.

Thanks.

Comment: Because writing a loop that iterates the array and composes the string is an obvious and boring solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var x=[[1, 2], [3, 4]];
JSON.stringify(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this JSON encode function:

http://www.openjs.com/scripts/data/json_encode.php

It should give you approximately what you want and is crossbrowser compatible, but it's not a one-liner.